# angular code optimization about $http request

Tags: angularjs, http

my code :

```
    app.factory('requestData',function($http,$q){
       return {
        reqData:function(params,url){
            return $http.get(url,{"params":params}).then(function(data){
                return data.data
            });
        });

    requestData.reqData( {module:"channel"},'/channel' ).then(function(data){
            $scope.selectChannel = data.value;
        })
     .then(function(){

         requestData.reqData( {channel_id:$scope.selectChannel},'/channel').then(function(data){
             $scope.summary = data.summary;
         })

      })
     .then(function(){
        //use $scope.summary do something
      });
```

firstly,i must set "$scope.selectChannel" value by asynchronous,then i  use "$scope.selectChannel" to request. there is another method to achieve?

Comment: There is a mismatch of brackets in your code. What is the opening bracket for the one you are closing at line 7?

Comment: Did either of these answers solve your problem?

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
app.factory('RequestData',function($http,$q) {
    var RequestData = {
        // assuming params is an object
        reqData: function(params) {
            $http.post('/channel', params).then(function(response){
                RequestData.selectChannel = response.value;
            });
        }
    };

    return RequestData;
});
```

In your controller, inject `RequestData` as a dependency then set `$scope.RequestData = RequestData` then you will have access to `RequestData.selectChannel` in your views.

Answer (score 1):

I advice you to use $resource instead.

```
.factory("$$service", ["$resource", function ($resource) {
    return $resource('/channel',
        {
            module: "@module",
            channel_id: "@channel_id"
        };
}]);
```

and use in this way:

```
var service = new $$service();
service.$get({"module":"channel"})
    .then(function(data){
        return service.$get({"channel_id":data.value});
    })
    .then(function(data){
        $scope.summary = data;
    });
```